# How to send comment using special Characters using javascript and GraphAPI

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I send ++++++++++&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& string like this to comment on any post using GRAPH API and javascript.

Answer (score 1):

just go to that link and see that files.           http://sudocode.net/sources/includes/class-xhttp-php

hope it will help you

Comment: I own the site that @magna links to and I know that you won't find anything useful on that page, in relation to the question.